# Rails Paginate Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

In my home controller I have

```
@list = Igraci.page(params[:page]).per(1)
```

In the index view

```
<%= paginate @list %>
```

and got this error:

```
undefined method 'page' for #<Class:0x235f256>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have `gem 'kaminari'` in your Gemfile, that you run `bundle` and restarted the server.

Additionally, someone had the [same issue](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/issues/213) as you, and their solution was to `require kaminari` in config/application.rb just before require 'rails/all'.

Comment: Thank you so much, Luis i solved the problem by adding gem'kaminari' in my gemfile, thanks so much :D